# Are checks for None threadsafe in CPython?

Tags: python, multithreading, thread-safety

I have a variation of a producer-consumer problem in Python (I want a number of producers that can produce exactly one item and immediately block waiting for it to be consumed, and a consumer that doesn't block and periodically polls if there is something to consume...) and I'm wondering whether the following code achieves this safely.

I'm especially interested in whether checking for None is threadsafe in Python:

```
class Worker(object):
    def __init__(...):
        self.item = None
        self.item_lock = threading.Lock()
        self.item_consumed = threading.Condition()

    def produce_something(...):
        with self.item_lock:
            self.item = make_a_complicated_data_structure()
            with self.item_consumed:
               while self.item is not None:
                   self.item_consumed.wait()

    def consume_it():
        if self.item is None:
            return
        with self.item_consumed:
            do_something_with(self.item)
            self.item = None
            self.item_consumed.notify()
```

Assume that there are a bunch of threads running `produce_something` and one thread that regularly polls `consume_it`.

I have several checks for "is not None" or "is None". Do these pose a problem? E.g. can something evil happen or are these checks thread safe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The title of your question asks:

> Are checks for `None` threadsafe in CPython?

A lot of things can go wrong in a multithreaded program, but `is [not] None` checks are not one of them.

In CPython, `None` is a singleton, so the check is tantamount to taking the address of the object and comparing it with a constant that's fixed for the lifetime of the process.

However, what you seem to be really asking is

> Is my code thread-safe?

To that I say "Why reinvent [`Queue.Queue(1)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html)?"

It does everything you want, simply and reliably. You don't need to roll out your own implementation and then wonder whether it's thread-safe.

Comment: Comparing Queue.Queue(1) to my above implementation, I noticed that not just does Queue.Queue everything I need it to do, it is also about 100 times faster (!). So we have a clear winner :-)